# Python3 List of binary data is not seen as bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am having problems trying to extract integers and bytes from a list of data in Phython3.  I read a serial port and capture a block of 282 bytes.  It is stored as a 'list' where tedData[0] is the whole block.  For example I need to extract bytes 249 and 250 and convert to a short integer.  Below is the basic commands I am using.  When I use the struct.unpack comand I get the error "a bytes-like object is reaqired, not a 'list'.
Any Suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
import serial
import struct

ser.serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",19200)

tedData = []

ser.write(b'\aa')              #request packet
tedData.append(ser.read(282))  # read in block of 282 bytes
kwh = struct.unpack(('<s', tedData[249:250]))
print("KWH's Today = ' + kwh)
ser.close()
```

Comment: You have a list with a single element, a `bytes` object. so you want `tedData[0][249:250]`. Note sure why you even have a `list` object at all... just use `tedData = ser.read(282)` and now you can use `tedData[249:250]`